# What´s missed in my ScanStreamTransformer function,2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found

Tags: flutter, reactive-programming, rxdart

I´m a flutter newbie and I have faced a problem when using ScanStreamTransformer with Future as accumulator.

```
    _itemTransformer() {
        return ScanStreamTransformer(
              (Future<TrailerModelEntity> trailer, int id, int index) {
            trailer = _repository.trailer(id);
            return trailer;
          },//what should be here to initialize the ´Future´
        );   
}
```

Comment: it also produce error The class 'TrailerModel' doesn't have a default constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'TrailerModel'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that worked with me :

```
  _itemTransformer() {
    return ScanStreamTransformer(
          (Future<TrailerModelEntity> trailer, int id, int index) {
        print(index);
        trailer = _repository.trailer(id);
        return trailer;
      },emptyFutureTrailerModel()
    );
  }

  Future<TrailerModelEntity> emptyFutureTrailerModel() async
  {
    return TrailerModelEntity();
  }
```

I just created an async method that returns an empty object as Future to initialize the accumulator.